# NSWindow Fullscreen, but show dock

Tags: objective-c, xcode, window, fullscreen, dock

Now I have finally managed to create a fullscreen window via http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000028.php
Brilliant tutorial. Now the question how do I use the following code to show the dock and menubar, as currently I have a completely black screen, I would like to see a menubar and a dock. Is that possible?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     int windowLevel;
     NSRect screenRect;
     // Capture the main display
     if (CGDisplayCapture( kCGDirectMainDisplay ) != kCGErrorSuccess) {
         NSLog( @"Couldn't capture the main display!" );
         // Note: you'll probably want to display a proper error dialog here
     }
     // Get the shielding window level
     windowLevel = CGShieldingWindowLevel();
     // Get the screen rect of our main display
     screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
     // Put up a new window
     mainWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect
                                    styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                    defer:NO screen:[NSScreen mainScreen]];
     [mainWindow setLevel:windowLevel];
     [mainWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
     [mainWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
     // Load our content view
     [slideShowPanel setFrame:screenRect display:YES];
     [mainWindow setContentView:[slideShowPanel contentView]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a bit of experimenting but I figured it out;

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
int windowLevel;
NSRect screenRect;
// Capture the main display

// Get the screen rect of our main display
screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
// Put up a new window
mainWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect
                                         styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                           backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                             defer:NO screen:[NSScreen mainScreen]];
[mainWindow setLevel:windowLevel];
[mainWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
[mainWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
// Load our content view
[slideShowPanel setFrame:screenRect display:YES];
[mainWindow setContentView:[slideShowPanel contentView]];

}
```

Comment: i diff'ed these and there is BARELY a difference...  where did you gain the functionality of being able to display the dock + menu bar?  i cant get it to work...

Comment: the windowLevel is not initialized before being used.  I'm guessing it randomly created the proper value to set the window level above the all other windows but below the value that was returned by CGShieldingWindowLevel().  I would highly encourage to do this in a proper fashion, like windowLevel=CGShieldingWindowLevel()-1;